# What set is this from? Or piece #

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I have this tote of LEGO bricks and wondering about the large Grey piece - large irregular light grey baseplate with two slopes running perpendicular to each other that don't have pips.

What set is it from so I can maybe download instructions.

[image: large irregular light grey baseplate with two slopes running perpendicular to each other that don't have pips.]

Comment: I don't recognize this as a LEGO piece. Does it have LEGO logo on studs?

Answer (score 6):

This is a Megabloks Baseplate ( MO1593 )

[Source](https://bloksforum.freeforums.net/thread/122/baseplate-14-images)

it is from set #1411

[Battle Shell Bridge](https://bricker.info/osets/MEGABLOKS/1411/)

[image]